# How to compare 2 URLs or check if my url contains a certain keyword in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to compare 2 urls.

If my url contains '/home' then it should do a certain action
and if it doesn't then it should just skip and move on to next line.

```
if(cy.url().should('contain, Cypress.config().baseUrl + '/home')){

   cy.get('[class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"]').last().click()
 }
```

So basically, if the url doesn't contain /home it should just skip but I am unable to do this because I am using an assertion and when it fails, it stops the test.

Comment: Do you have a sample of what a url should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of evaluating `cy.url().should()`, [you can yield the value of `cy.url()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url#Yields) and use it as a string value.

```js
cy.url().then((url) => {
  if (url.includes(`${Cypress.config('baseUrl')}/home`)) {
    // code to run
  }
});
```